# In Electron, how to preserve the original traffic light buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, electron, titlebar

When developing an Electron application on macOS, I want to set the window to have no frame and use the system's default traffic light buttons.

I initially planned to build one using HTML, but I realized that the one in VS Code is built-in. I couldn't find how to set it up.

[image]

I looked through the Electron documentation, but I didn't find the answer I'm seeking. I want to achieve the same effect as in VS Code. Have others also encountered this kind of requirement?

Comment: Please see [ask]. Your question needs improvement. Also, take the [tour]. Protip: Don't even mention chatbots here. They're a sore point and not often helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a package I made about last year called [Electron-Trubar](https://npmjs.com/package/electron-trubar) and customize background color, text, text color, seam color, and traffic light position.

First install it:

```bash
npm install electron-trubar
```

Then use it like this (setting traffic light position):

```js
const TruBar = require("electron-trubar");

TruBar(mainWindow, {
  trafficLightX: 6.5,
  trafficLightY: 6.5
});
```

And if you want a transparent window frame, BUT you also want traffic light buttons, set the "backgroundColor" property to "transparent" when setting up TruBar.

Make sure to use the `TruBar()` function *after* initialization.

**Note** that you don't need this package to do this. It is just an easier and more simple method to customizing the window's taskbar.

Electron has a built-in funtion just for doing this:

```js
mainWindow.setTrafficLightPosition({ x: 6.5, y: 6.5 });
```

Comment: Thank you for the ideas you provided. I found the answer through the official documentation.
I achieved the desired effect by setting the BrowserWindow property titleBarStyle to hidden and titleBarOverlay to true

Comment: @mjx nice to know! Sometimes it just takes a little looking around to figure it out, lol